# Сохранение и считывание значений полей объекта

Tags: c++

Пишу небольшую симуляцию мира. Необходимо реализовать сохранение текущего состояния + загрузку состояния из файла.
Есть Класс World:

```
class World
{
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    int turn = 1;
    vector<Organism*> organisms;
    ...
}
```

Вектор содержит объекты разных организмов.

```
class Organism
{
private:
    int power;
    int speed;
    char orgSymb;
    bool alive;
    int nowX;
    int nowY;
    int lastX;
    int lastY;
}
```

Как можно реализовать сохранение полей объекта класса мир, для последующей загрузки и продолжения симуляции мира?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да в вашем случае как раз все просто - записать (бинарно) поля `World` - `width`, `height`, `turn`. Потом - количество объектов в векторе, а затем в цикле - все `Organism` из вектора. Если это простая структура, без виртуальных функций - можно просто `ofstream::write(organisms[i],sizeof(Organism))`. Если нет - то по полям.

Читать - опять же, считали поля `World`, потом - количество организмов. Потом цикл до этого количества - создание нового организма (`new Organism`), чтение в него данных, внесение в вектор.

Думаю, особых проблем с кодом быть не должно...